# Problem facing while querying for wild card queries

Tags: solr, wildcard

I am using solr for indexing and searching in my application. I am facing some strange problem while querying wild card
When i search for `di?mo?d`, i get results for diamond but when i search for `diamo??` i get no results.What could be the reason please tell.

**EDIT:**

```
 <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true" maxPosAsterisk="6" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/> 
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>


      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: Please post some more details about the fieldType, queryHandler analyzers and tokenizers used

Comment: @Prasanna: Please look at the edit for more info.

Comment: Just to confirm, your search is not phrase query right? For eg: you are not searching for: what is diamo?? but just: diamo??. Can you try diamon? and see whether it works?